# How to delegate traits functionality to member of class?

Tags: c++, c++11, delegates, traits

I'm searching for a way to delegate trait functionality to member. Inheritance is not an option at this point.
So assume we have a class `B` and 2 different Traits already working with that class.

```
struct B
{};

template<typename T>
struct Trait1
{
    static
    void foo1(T t)
    {}
};

template<>
struct Trait1<B>
{
    static
    void foo1(B t)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Trait2
{
    static
    void foo2(T t)
    {}
};

template<>
struct Trait2<B>
{
    static
    void foo2(B t)
    {}
};
```

I also have an aggregate class `C` with 2 members of that class `B`, like:

```
struct C
{
    B m1;
    B m2;
};
```

Now I want to define the both Traits for that class `C` as well, with delegating to the appropriate member. The plain approach would be s.th. like:

```
template<>
struct Trait1<C>
{
    static
    void foo1(C t)
    {
        Trait1<B>::foo1(t.m1);
    }
};

template<>
struct Trait2<C>
{
    static
    void foo2(C t)
    {
        Trait2<B>::foo2(t.m2);
    }
};
```

For traits with a lot of functions that is kind of annoying and probably has copy-paste errors. So the question arised to me, is there a way to delegate the functionality in an elegant way (C++11 preferred, C++14/17 also possible)? Meaning In case of `Trait1` use member `m1` and for `Trait2` use member `m2`.
Thanks for help.

**EDIT**: methods of the `Trait1` and `Trait2` have actually different names.
And in the wild a macro replacing 1 with 2 will not work, so I would encourage not to use macros.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a generic traits for factorize code

```
template<template <typename> class Trait, typename T, typename T2, T2 (T::*M)>
struct GenTrait
{
    static
    void foo(T t)
    {
        Trait<T2>::foo(t.*M);
    }
};
```

And then

```
template<>
struct Trait1<C> : GenTrait<Trait1, C, B, &C::m1> {};

template<>
struct Trait2<C> : GenTrait<Trait2, C, B, &C::m2> {};
```

Comment: Looks nice - only drawback: you have to duplicate the interface in GenTrait again, admitted, only once, though. But if you now found a way to apply the GenTrait for the Trait<B> and template<typename T>Trait as well, this would be the absolutely superior solution...

Answer (score 2):

First, I needed executor template functions. These are the ones to do perform whatever has to be done and to be specialised or overloaded for other classes:

```
template<typename T>
void theFoo1(T t)
{
    std::cout << "foo 1" << std::endl;
}
template<typename T>
void theFoo2(T t)
{
    std::cout << "foo 2" << std::endl;
}
struct B
{};
void theFoo1(B t)
{
    std::cout << "foo 1 B" << std::endl;
}
void theFoo2(B t)
{
    std::cout << "foo 2 B" << std::endl;
}
```

Then, I need getter templates that provide the appropriate data:

```
template<typename T>
inline T get1(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
inline T get2(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

My traits no look like this; note: you won't specialise these any more at any time:

```
template<typename T>
struct Trait1
{
    static inline
    void foo(T t)
    {
        theFoo1(get1(t));
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Trait2
{
    static inline
    void foo(T t)
    {
        theFoo2(get2(t));
    }
};
```

Now C comes into play; B is already ready for use, so we can simply continue with C itself; all I need is two additional overloads:

```
struct C
{
    B m1;
    B m2;
};
B get1(C t)
{
    return t.m1;
}
B get2(C t)
{
    return t.m2;
}
```

Finally: test it...

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
    B b;
    Trait2<B>::foo(b);
    C c;
    Trait1<C>::foo(c);
    Trait2<C>::foo(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to your specific requirement (where you need `m1` & `m2`), there is no way to avoid re-writing lot of code for `class C` separately. To avoid such copy pasting, you may use simple macros. Pseudo code:

```
#define TRAIT_C(N, FUNCTION) \
  template<> \
  struct Trait##N<C> \
  { \
    static \
    void foo(C t) \
    { \
      Trait##N<B>::foo(t.m##N); \
    } \
  }
```

Now use this in a "eye-soothing" way while defining trait for `B`:

```
template<>
struct Trait1<B>
{
  static
  void foo(B t)
  {}
};
TRAIT_C(1, foo);  // This inlines the complete version of `Trait1` for `C`
```

Here is a [demo-ideone](http://ideone.com/Tvby2Y) or [demo-coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f508664964dd4299).

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the pointers to data members as part of the traits itself.
It can be done by means of template variables (named `data` in the example below).

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
struct B {};

template<typename T>
struct Trait1;

template<>
struct Trait1<B>
{
    template<typename U>
    static constexpr B U::* data = &U::m1;

    static
    void foo(B t)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Trait2;

template<>
struct Trait2<B>
{
    template<typename U>
    static constexpr B U::* data = &U::m2;

    static
    void foo(B t)
    {}
};

struct C
{
    B m1;
    B m2;
};

template<>
struct Trait1<C>
{
    using BT = Trait1<B>;
    static constexpr B C::* data = BT::data<C>;

    static
    void foo(C t)
    {
        BT::foo(t.*data);
    }
};

template<>
struct Trait2<C>
{
    static
    void foo(C t)
    {
        Trait2<B>::foo(t.*Trait2<B>::data<C>);
    }
};
```

In the example above, `Trait1<C>` and `Trait2<C>` differ in order to show two possible solutions (I would use the first one if I had the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

After inspiration by some of the proposals (e.g. @Aconcagua ) I thought of a `DelegateTrait` itself, like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename TraitT, typename DelegateT>
struct DelegateTrait
{
    typedef DelegateT MemberT;// type of member delegated to

    // method for delegation to specific member
    static
    MemberT forward(DelegateT delegate)
    {
        return delegate;
    }
};
```

Now a small adaption of the original `Trait1` is needed

```
template<typename T, typename DelegateT = void>
struct Trait1
{
    static
    void foo1(T t)
    {
        std::cout << "default Trait1<T>::foo1()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Trait1<
    T,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, typename DelegateTrait<Trait1<T>, T>::MemberT>::value>::type>
{
    static
        void foo1(T t)
    {
        std::cout << "delegate Trait1<T>::foo1()" << std::endl;
        Trait1<typename DelegateTrait<Trait1<T>, T>::MemberT>::foo1(DelegateTrait<Trait1<T>, T>::forward(t));
    }
};

template<>
struct Trait1<B>
{
    static
    void foo1(B t)
    {
        std::cout << "Trait1<B>::foo1()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In a similar way an adaption of `Trait2` is done. The `std::enable_if` is used to avoid recursive (and endless) calling of the same method.

You now have to specialize the `DelegateTrait` for each combination of class and trait where you want to forward to s.th. else but the instance of the given class.

```
template<>
struct DelegateTrait<Trait1<C>, C>
{
    typedef B MemberT;
    static
    MemberT forward(C delegate)
    {
        std::cout << "forward C to C.m1" << std::endl;
        return delegate.m1;
    }
};

template<>
struct DelegateTrait<Trait2<C>, C>
{
    typedef B MemberT;
    static
    MemberT forward(C delegate)
    {
        std::cout << "forward C to C.m2" << std::endl;
        return delegate.m2;
    }
};
```

You can still specialize for the class itself if you don't want to forward, like:

```
struct D
{
    D(){};
    B m1;
    B m2;
};

template<>
struct Trait2<D>
{
    static
    void foo2(D t)
    {
        std::cout << "Trait<D>::foo2(), no delegate" << std::endl;
    }
};


int
    main(
        int     argc,
        char ** argv)
{
    C c;
    Trait1<C>::foo1(c);//delegates to m1
    Trait2<C>::foo2(c);//delegates to m2

    D d;
    Trait1<D>::foo1(d);//default trait implementation
    Trait2<D>::foo2(d);//trait specialization for D

    return 0;
}
```

Of course that solution needs a extension of the original trait. Do you see some other issue coming with that approach, e.g. performance?